# C++: how generate more then one set of random values

Tags: c++, inheritance

I wrote a code to generate a player, but am stuck on how to generate a 2nd one.
I will eventually need to work with a whole bunch of them./n
There must be something extremely elementary that i am missing...

Class Definition

```
class Player
{
public:
    Player(personal_information pi, player_skill pskill, player_trait ptrait);
    void generatePlayer();

private:
    personal_information pinfo;
    player_skill pskill;
    player_trait ptrait;
};
```

Class implementation

```
Player::Player(personal_information pi, player_skill psk, player_trait pt)
{
    this->pinfo = pi;
    this->pskill = psk;
    this->ptrait = pt;
}
```

Generate player fun

```
void Player::generatePlayer()
{
    printf(" %s %s (%dyo, %dcm, %dkg)\n", this->pinfo.first_name, this->pinfo.last_name, this->pinfo.years, this->pinfo.height, this->pinfo.weight);
    printf("   Can play as (%s)\n", this->pskill.position);
    printf(" Player Skills:\n");
    printf("   Fitness (%d)\n", this->pskill.fitness);
    printf("   Strenght (%d)\n", this->pskill.strenght);
    printf("   Goalkeeping (%d)\n", this->pskill.goalkeeping);
    printf("   Passing (%d)\n", this->pskill.passing);
    printf("   Shooting (%d)\n", this->pskill.shooting);
    printf(" Traits:");
//  printf("\n");
//  printf(" Player is");
if (true == this->ptrait.tall) { printf(" Tall"); };
if (true == this->ptrait.raz) {printf(" Short");};
if (true == this->ptrait.fat) {printf(" Fat");};
if (true == this->ptrait.skinny) {printf(" Skinny");};
    printf(".\n");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Main

```
int main()
{
    initSystem();

    // Random player generator data
    personal_information pi = { 0 };
        pi.first_name = nameEng[rand() % ARR_SIZE(nameEng)];
        pi.last_name = nameEngSurname[rand() % ARR_SIZE(nameEngSurname)];
        pi.years = Min_Age_Player + random(Min_Age_Player - Max_Age_Player);
        pi.height = MIN_HEIGHT + random(MAX_HEIGHT - MIN_HEIGHT);
//      pi.height = 140;
        pi.weight = MIN_WEIGHT + random(MAX_WEIGHT - MIN_WEIGHT);
//      pi.weight = 120;
    player_skill psk = { 0 };
        psk.position = positionsList[rand() % ARR_SIZE(positionsList)];
        psk.fitness = random(10);
        psk.strenght = random(10);
        psk.goalkeeping = random(5);
        psk.passing = random(10);
        psk.shooting = random(10);
    player_trait pt = { 0 };
            //  tall/short
        if (pi.height > 186) {pt.tall = true;
            psk.goalkeeping = psk.goalkeeping + 2;
        };
        if (pi.height < 165) { pt.raz = true;
            psk.goalkeeping = psk.goalkeeping - 2;
        };
            //  fat/skinny
        if (pi.weight > 100) { pt.fat = true;
            psk.fitness = psk.fitness - 2;
            psk.strenght = psk.strenght + 2;
        };
        if (pi.weight < 85) { pt.skinny = true;
            psk.strenght = psk.strenght - 2;
        };
    Player P1genStats(pi, psk, pt);
    P1genStats.generatePlayer();

    Player P2genStats(pi, psk, pt);
    P2genStats.generatePlayer();

    return 0;
}
```

I was naiive enough to think this will yield me 2 separate sets of values, but when i run it, it gives me the same set of values twice.

Essentially giving me the same player twice.

Ideally i would not want this to even be in main, what would be the most elegant way to write a single function to generate a player with these stats?

Comment: What is `nameEng` and `ARR_SIZE` (among others)? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, something which we can copy-paste and try ourselves to see your behavior. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: First question: You are creating two objects with the same initialisation parameters. Why should they be any different?

Comment: The second question is off-topic, you may want to ask this e.g. on "Code Review". But a short hint anyway: Move each initialisation from main into the corresponding class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your random generating code twice if you want two different player's.

If you think about it your `generatePlayer` function doesn't do anything of the sort. It only prints a players statistics. A better name for the function would be `printPlayer`.

The real generating code is all the code you have in main, that generates random information. So maybe your code would be better structured like this (I've abbreviated for the sake of clarity). In this code the `Player` constructor calls the random code, so all players will have random stats.

```
class Player
{
public:
    Player(); // generate player with random stats
    void printPlayer();

private:
    personal_information pinfo;
    player_skill pskill;
    player_trait ptrait;
};

Player::Player()
{
    pinfo.first_name = nameEng[rand() % ARR_SIZE(nameEng)];
    pinfo.last_name = nameEngSurname[rand() % ARR_SIZE(nameEngSurname)];
    ...
    pskill.position = positionsList[rand() % ARR_SIZE(positionsList)];
    pskill.fitness = random(10);
    ...
}

int main()
{
    Player P1genStats;
    P1genStats.printPlayer();

    Player P2genStats;
    P2genStats.printPlayer();
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding a parameter to that constructor, for the source of randomness. A default constructor shouldn't give different values each time.